# CircleCI: Unable to get path of apk generated in another job in same workflow

Tags: android, circleci

I'm implementing APK distribution with Firebase App Distribution Using [Circle CI](https://circleci.com/) and In which I have a workflow with 2 jobs, One job build the APK and the second one deploy it on Firebase App Distribution.

```
version: 2.1

jobs:
  build:
    working_directory: ~/code
    docker:
      - image: circleci/android:api-29
    environment:
      JVM_OPTS: -Xmx2g
      GRADLE_OPTS:  '-Dkotlin.compiler.execution.strategy="in-process"'
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run:
          name: Create keystore.jks
          command: echo $RELEASE_KEY_BASE64 | base64 --decode > $RELEASE_KEY_STORE
      - run:
          name: Create keystore.properties
          command: printf 'releaseKeyAlias=%s\nreleaseKeyPassword=%s\nreleaseKeyStore=%s\nreleaseStorePassword=%s' $RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS $RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD $RELEASE_KEY_STORE $RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD > keystore.properties
      - restore_cache:
          key: jars-{{ checksum "build.gradle" }}-{{ checksum  "app/build.gradle" }}
      - run:
          name: Download Dependencies
          command: ./gradlew androidDependencies
      - save_cache:
          paths:
            - ~/.gradle
          key: jars-{{ checksum "build.gradle" }}-{{ checksum  "app/build.gradle" }}
      - run:
          name: Run Tests
          command: ./gradlew lint test
      - run:
          name: Run UnitTest
          command: ./gradlew test
      - store_artifacts:
          path: app/build/reports
          destination: reports
      - store_test_results:
          path: app/build/test-results
      - run:
          name: Initial build
          command: ./gradlew clean assembleRelease --no-daemon --stacktrace
      - store_artifacts:
          path: app/build/outputs/apk/
          destination: apks/

  deploy:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/ruby:2.4-node
    working_directory: ~/code
    shell: /bin/bash --login -o pipefail
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run:
          name: Install Firebase CLI
          command: curl -sL https://firebase.tools | bash
      - run:
          name: Distribute APK to Firebase
          command: firebase appdistribution:distribute "/home/circleci/code/app/build/outputs/apk/release/app-release.apk" --app $FIREBASE_APP_ID --token $FIREBASE_TOKEN --release-notes "Test Release Note" --groups $FIREBASE_TEST_GROUP --debug

workflows:
  version: 2.0
  build-deploy:
    jobs:
      - build:
      - deploy:
          requires:
            - build
```

And When I access the APK in deploy job which was generated in build Job, I got the below error.
**Error:** File /home/circleci/code/app/build/outputs/apk/release/app-release.apk does not exist: verify that file points to a distribution.

But The same code is working in a single job.
Is there any way to get the file access to another job?

Comment: You are using 2 different jobs. The data won't persist between jobs as different docker spins on each jobs. Checkout https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/caching/ this link for caching data and using between jobs.

Comment: Thanks @karikevinod its working.

Answer (score 0):

I know I was able to share this workspace between the build and deliver

```
executors:
  my-xecutor:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/android:api-29-node
    working_directory: ~/repo/MYAPP


jobs:
  build:
    executor: my-xecutor

    environment:
      JVM_OPTS: -Xmx4G

    steps:
      # Clone the repo
      - checkout:
          path: ~/repo

      # Build and test, using cached assets if possible
      - restore_cache: &CACHE_KEY
          key: jars-{{ checksum "build.gradle" }}-{{ checksum  "app/build.gradle" }}
      # build.sh is not shown here too complex and app specific
      - run:
          name: Build and test
          command: ../scripts/build.sh 

      - save_cache:
          <<: *CACHE_KEY
          paths:
            - ~/.gradle

      # Make test results show up in the CircleCI build dashboard
      - run:
          name: Save test results
          command: |
            mkdir -p ~/junit/
            find . -type f -regex ".*/build/test-results/.*xml" -exec cp {} ~/junit/ \;
          when: always

      - store_test_results:
          path: ~/junit

      - store_artifacts:
          path: ~/junit

      - persist_to_workspace:
          root: ~/repo
          paths:
            - scripts
            - MYAPP/app/build.gradle
            - MYAPP/app/build/outputs/apk/release.notes.txt
            - MYAPP/app/build/outputs/apk/*/*/

    - run:
        command: |
          ls -l app/build/outputs/apk/*/*/
        
    - run:
        command: cat /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/memory.max_usage_in_bytes
        when: always

  deliver:
    executor: my-xecutor

    steps:
      - attach_workspace:
          at: ./

      - run:
          command: |
            ls -lR .

      - run:
          name: Download appcenter
          command: |
            sudo npm install appcenter-cli -g

    # then run your upload to appcenter cli command and use the path
    # MYAPP/app/build/outputs/apk/{debug|release}/app_file_name.apk
    # I also attached release notes to upload
```